# base R panel residual plot labels

Tags: r, plot

How do I alter the plot so the full text of each panel is visible?

```
plot(m7, form = resid(., type = "pearson") ~ fitted(.) | Region, abline = 0, cex = .5, pch = 20, col = "black", xlab = "Fitted values", ylab = "Pearson residuals")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you drag your plot window it should work in Rstudio, but below are a few other options. First using a simulated data:

```
library(lme4)

data = sleepstudy
data$Subject = paste0("Subject",data$Subject)
data = subset(data,Subject %in% unique(data$Subject)[1:14])
```

You facet it to have more rows:

```
fit = lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data)
plot(fit,form =resid(., type = "pearson") ~ fitted(.) | Subject, 
abline = 0, cex = .5, pch = 20, col = "black",layout=c(4,4), 
xlab = "Fitted values", ylab = "Pearson residuals")
```

[image]

Or you plot it on a png that's wide enough:

```
png("test.png",width=800,height=400)

fit = lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data)
    plot(fit,form =resid(., type = "pearson") ~ fitted(.) | Subject, 
    abline = 0, cex = .5, pch = 20, col = "black", 
    xlab = "Fitted values", ylab = "Pearson residuals")

dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, rearranging the grid to a 3x5 did the trick